# Brakeman Redirect warning: False positive?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, security, redirect, brakeman

Following snippet is marked as "Possible unprotected redirect":

```
  redirect_to(NotificationStatus.where(
    :victim => current_user, 
    :notification_id => params[:id]).first.notification.redirect_url
  )
```

NotificationStatus is an ActiveRecord model and `belongs_to` notification model. `redirect_url` is a field of notification.

I think this is false positive, however I am not sure. Could a redirect be possible outside of my app?

Comment: Depends how these notification objects are created - where does its redirect_url come from?

Comment: Isn't `redirect_url` field of notification my only concern here? That field doesn't come from user input. I think it is reporting *redirect warning* cause `params[:id]` exists in the code. However, user can't send anything which many lead to malicious redirect. `params[:id]` has to be an integer (primary key of NotificationStatus). If it isn't then object won't be found. Thats it!

Comment: brakeman has no way of knowing who / what can set the redirect_url property of the notification, which is why I think it logs a warning

Comment: @FrederickCheung is correct. It is not warning about `params[:id]`, it's warning about `redirect_url` since that might be user input (it's coming from a database model).